# How to make my webpage stop refreshing when button is clicked and ajax function is ran?

Tags: html, css, ajax

I'm creating a virtual remote using flask, html, and ajax. I'm trying to make a webpage that simulates a remote by using button clicks. I copied multiple templates to get the one I have right now but for some reason it refreshes the page when I click a button. I removed the css because it was too much code for stackoverflow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>GFG</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" id="todo-form">
    <div class ="circleBase" id="rotateMode">  
        <!-- <button id="left" class="btn btn-default btn-sm"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span></button> -->
        <button id ='left' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' name='button' value='left'></button>
        <button id ='right' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' name='button' value='right'></button>
        <button id ='up' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' name='button'value='up'></button>
        <button id ='down' class='btn btn-default btn-sm' name='button'value='down'></button>

    </form>
 
        <!--Jquery Cdn -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on('submit','#todo-form',function(e)
                 {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type:'POST',
      url:'/controller',
      data:{
        $(this).val():value
      },
      success:function()
      {
      }
    })
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try add type="button" to your button, by default button inside form will treat as a submit button. thank add the ajax when button click instead of form submit.

Comment: Thanks so much it works now. What I did was add type="button" and under the ajax I replaced the $(document).on('submit','#todo-form',function(e) with $("button").click(function(e)